# Adaptive ODE algorithm in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, math, scipy, ode

I want to integrate a particle path in 2D using the `integrate.ode` module. Things that are a bit different in my case are that, I only want to integrate up to a certain position, determined by the maximum allowed x coordinate of the particle: `x_max`.

The main issue I have is that the particle may first move very slowly and then gather more speed later on. Hence I don't want to waste effort with small time steps in this region. The algorithm should be able to adjust such that smaller time steps are used when the particle velocity becomes high.

I have some rough pseudo-code below for this purpose:

```
backend = "dopri5"
x_max = 1
solver = ode(f)
solver.set_integrator(backend)  
solver.set_initial_value(y0, t0)
t, y = [t0], [y0]
k = 1.2
while solver.successful() and solver.y[0] < x_max
   solver.integrate(solver.t+dt)
   t.append(solver.t)
   y.append(solver.y)
   v_current = numpy.linalg.norm(y[-1])
   v_previous = numpy.linalg.norm(y[-2])
   if numpy.abs( v_current-v_previous ) > k * v_previous:
       dt = 0.8*dt
       del y[-1]
   else:
       dt = dt*1.2
```

Trouble is this algorithm may not be that robust, as choosing the values `k, 1.2, 0.8` is somewhat arbitrary and may cause some stability issues with the algorithm.

Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this?

Comment: This might be better suited to http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AndrewWalker Ah ok sorry, should I re-post my question there?

Comment: IMO it's not off topic, but it is reasonably specific, I think you'll probably get much better answers from the audience on scicomp.

Comment: Ok great,  is there a preferred way to do it, i.e. by "migrating" or do I just sign up there and post a new question?

Answer (score 4):

For combining discrete events (a crossing) with ODEs you might want to try a library with functionality specifically designed for such problems. There appear to be a few:

- [PyDSTool](http://www.ni.gsu.edu/~rclewley/PyDSTool/FrontPage.html)
- [Assimulo2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Assimulo/2.5.1)
- [scikits.ode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scikits.odes)

If you the structure of your model implies you will always detect events, you may be able to take large steps and use binary search to find the time/location at which events occur. This typically doesn't work where there is more than one dimension.

This type of problem occurs frequently in game programming / real-time physics / collision detection, and you may have some luck using techniques from that field (think fast moving bullets passing through slow moving entities).

If you're trying to respond to an event occuring, say something like a bouncing ball, you're really in the space of [hybrid systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_system)